# Does dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: call an initializer in my UITableViewCell subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController subclass with its prototype cells mocked up in the storyboard.

There's a fair amount of code in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method that sets up the cells. Problem is I don't need most of it if the cell is just being dequeued from the reuse pool, because it's already been done when the cell was dequeued the first time. I can't do it in the storyboard because there are some properties I can only access programmatically.

Does the UITableViewController call an initializer in my UITableViewCell subclass when it takes a prototype cell from the storyboard? I tried `(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` but that does not appear to be part of the process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a UITableView instance calls for `dequeueReusableTileWithIdentifier:`, the cell is not reinitialized. Instead, in that call, the UITableViewCell that is dequeued will call `-(void)prepareForReuse`. This is because reinitializing the cell is costly, and if we can provide a much simpler method for preparing for its reuse (eh, eh, get it?) it saves a whole lot of CPU work.

Ergo, if you're using custom cells, override UITableViewCell `prepareForReuse`.

Answer (score 11):

I probably didn't phrase my question properly but I was looking for here was actually `(void)awakeFromNib`.

Gets called once when the cell is dequeued and not on reuse. Allows me to do some setup programmatically that it doesn't make sense to do in the storyboard.

Comment: (vodi)awakeFromNib works perfect for stuff you want to happen only once, like adding a gesture recognizer to a UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are loading (deserializing) the cell from the storyboard (nib-file) `-[UITableViewCell initWithCoder:]` method is  called.